# How to get file extension?

Tags: java, command, system

Here is my code that I have developed but I got stuck on one thing. I want to make my program recognize what file extension is the file within my directory.

```
import java.io.File;
public class SystemCommands{

   public static void main (String args[]){

      String dir_name = "C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR"; 
      File dir = new File(dir_name);

      File[] dir_list = dir.listFiles();
      for(int i=0;i<dir_list.length;++i)
      {
          System.out.println(dir_list[i].getName());
          System.out.println("Is it a directory = " + dir_list[i].isDirectory());
          System.out.println("Is it a file = " + dir_list[i].isFile());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "recognize"? You want to filter them or what?

Comment: Specify the filter on the type of file. For example inside WinRAR I have winrar.txt and the program will say winrar.txt has the .txt extension.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String#lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) and simply do:

```
String file = dir_list[i].toString();
System.out.println(file.substring(0, file.lastIndexOf('.')));
```

Or, preferable, you can use [`FilenameUtils#getExtension`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29):

```
System.out.println(FilenameUtils.getExtension(yourString));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String filename=null;    
for(int i=0;i<dir_list.length;++i)
       {
        filename=dir_list[i].getName();
        if(dir_list[i].isFile())
         {
           System.out.println(filename.split(\\.)[(filename.split(\\.)).length-1]);
         }

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FilenameUtils.getExtension from Apache Commons IO

Here is an example of use:

```
String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension("/path/file/file.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one...


File fileName= new File("Animation.xml");    
String str= fileName.getName();    
System.out.println(fileName.getName());    
System.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".")));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
File f = new File("test.txt");
            String [] str = f.getName().split("\\.");
            if(str.length>1) {
                System.out.println(str[1]);
            }else {
                System.out.println("No extension. File name is :" + str[0]);
            }
```

Comment: It's not necessary to be 1st index is extension.

Comment: @Deepak213 can you give me an example please?

Comment: Like if the file name is "abc.abc.txt" then your case will fail.

Comment: @Deepak213 is right. You should use `lastIndexOf` instead of `split`, or print the last element in `str`.

Comment: But the problem with checking the last index is, it will not give correct extension for files like "test.log.0","test.tar.gz" .... do you agree?

Comment: if you want to do it according to your way then use filename.split(\\.)[(filename.split(\\.)).length-1]

Comment: I tried all of the answers but can't get them to work. I want code that will just print out the extensions of the Files within the directory used. For example in WinRAR\\WinRAR.txt = .txt extension

Comment: The issue with your solution if(filename.split(\\.)[(filename.split(\\.)).length-1].equals("any file extension")) --- is that the user doesnt know what extension he is looking for. He just wants to list down all the extensions of files available.Or maybe I am wrong. Could you please explain your solution?

Comment: Yes I just want a list of all the file extensions: For example WinRAR.txt the extension is .txt

Comment: @user3351284 Just see my edited answer it will give you all extensions in string form if you want then you can store it in array. Is there any thing else you want?